# Did Draco Malfoy know that he is related to Sirius Black?

Tags: harry-potter, genealogy, sirius-black

Sirius Black is Draco Malfoy's first cousin once removed. According to an [answer](https://www.quora.com/Was-Sirius-Black-the-uncle-of-Draco-Malfoy/answer/Jasneet-Singh-58?srid=1oC4) in Quora:

> Since, the Malfoy and Black were all about pure blood and stuff, they also married in pure bloods. Narcissa, cousin of Sirius and Regulus Black married Lucius Malfoy.

And at this [answer.](http://harrypotter.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Is_draco_malfoy_related_to_Sirius)

Regardless with the answer, did Draco know that Sirius is his cousin or even related to him?

Comment: He almost certainly knows.

Comment: Well, his mum knew that she had a connection to his elf. That means Sirius's genealogy was probably common knowledge in the Malfoy family.

Comment: plus, Sirius was the black (excuse the pun) sheep of the family, so it probably wasn't talked about much - except for things like 'if you're friends with that muggle you'll end up like Sirius!' or whatever.

Comment: Genealogy was a big thing with the pure-blood wizard families (and as Sirius said, there aren't that many of them). I'm sure the Malfoys, Draco included, knew the names of all of the old British wizarding families and how they were related to them and each other.

Comment: Sirius Black is not the _uncle_ of Draco Malfoy. You say yourself that Draco's mother Narcissa (née Black, by the way) and Sirius were cousins – first cousins, in fact. That makes Sirius and Draco first cousins once removed.

Comment: @tobiasvl [Malfoy family tree on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-malfoy-family-tree). I'm not an expert in this, but Sirius and Draco are on its opposite ends.

Comment: @Gallifreyan But from the tree you see that Cygnus (Narcissa's father) and Walberga (Sirius's mother) are siblings, making Narcissa and Sirius first cousins like I said. What do you mean by opposite ends?

Comment: @tobiasvl I'm _really_ not good at reading those :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan Hehe! But thanks, that tree is a good source that I should add to my answer :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### I can't imagine he doesn't know, and he certainly knows after events in the fifth book.

To all wizards, at least the pure-bloods (except oblivious Harry), it's well known that all pure-blood wizarding families are interrelated. When Harry finds out Sirius and Draco are related, Sirius just shrugs it off.

> Harry, however, did not laugh; he was
> too busy staring at the names to the right of
> Andromeda’s burn mark. A double line of gold
> embroidery linked Narcissa Black with Lucius Malfoy,
> and a single vertical gold line from their names led to
> the name Draco.

> “You’re related to the Malfoys!”

> “The pure-blood families are all interrelated,” said
> Sirius. “If you’re only going to let your sons and
> daughters marry purebloods your choice is very
> limited, there are hardly any of us left. Molly and I are
> cousins by marriage and Arthur’s something like my
> second cousin once removed. But there’s no point
> looking for them on here — if ever a family was a
> bunch of blood traitors it’s the Weasleys.”

Sirius is the black sheep in the Black family; they were mostly followers of Voldemort, and some of them even Death Eaters. Both the Blacks and the Malfoys were very old wizarding families, and the fact that Narcissa's maiden name was Black couldn't have escaped Draco for long if he even put the least effort into his own genealogy.

Of course, it *is* possible that Narcissa Malfoy (née Black) has neglected to mention to her son Draco that she and Sirius Black are first cousins. Sirius was disowned by the Black family, after all, and his portrait burned off the Black family tapestry in Grimmauld Place 12.

Even if she never told him and nobody else did either, Draco would certainly be aware of it after the following interview was published in *The Daily Prophet* after the mass Azkaban breakout in *The Order of the Phoenix*:

> Speaking to reporters in his private office, Cornelius
> Fudge, Minister of Magic, confirmed that ten high security
> prisoners escaped in the early hours of
> yesterday evening, and that he has already informed
> the Muggle Prime Minister of the dangerous nature of
> these individuals.

> “We find ourselves, most unfortunately, in the same
> position we were two and a half years ago when the
> murderer Sirius Black escaped,” said Fudge last night.
> “Nor do we think the two breakouts are unrelated. An
> escape of this magnitude suggests outside help, and
> we must remember that Black, as the first person ever
> to break out of Azkaban, would be ideally placed to
> help others follow in his footsteps. We think it likely
> that these individuals, who include **Black’s cousin,
> Bellatrix Lestrange**, have rallied around Black as their
> leader. We are, however, doing all we can to round up
> the criminals and beg the magical community to remain
> alert and cautious. On no account should any of these
> individuals be approached.”

It was certainly no secret to Draco that Bellatrix Lestrange was Narcissa's sister, and his aunt. Although she was locked into Azkaban for most of Draco's life, they spent quite an amount of time together after she escaped, and killing her cousin was on top of her to-do list and probably something she bragged about afterwards (she usually called him her "dear cousin" derisively).